# Remove the_content From Loop

Tags: php, categories, loop

I'm trying to display a custom loop with only certain elements in it.

My loop currently contains the title, creation date, author & content.

However I am trying to remove the content for each post in the loop as I do not want it displayed in this list with no luck.

I have even removed the_content() out of the loop & it still displays a listing of the post content under the looped section.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

here is my code:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=halloween &posts_per_page=6'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<!-- IF articles then display them -->

<h6><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h6>   
<small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></small>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<!-- IF no articles were created then show -->

NO Posts Present 

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I seemed to have found what i was missing in my code as there needed to be the following snippet of code required at the end of my loop which fixed the issue:

here is the code which I added after my endif

    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

Comment: Please, [don't Multi-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/185667) the same Question [across the network](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15182209/1287812).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything that would cause the_content() to display in your code. Chances are, the template file you are editing is NOT the one being used on the page/archive you are checking.

Add this to the top of your template files...

```
<!-- Template: <?php echo __file__;  ?> -->
```

Now, in your web browser view source and locate "Template:" - which will tell you which template file(s) are being loaded for the current page. From there, you will be able to figure out which template file you *should* be working on. It might be the wrong file, or it might be the right file in the wrong theme.